# Xamarin Forms : iOS Linking

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, linker

I am trying to enable "`Link All`" in the **Xamarin Forms** Apps.It was successfully done in Android.But for , it's **iOS** version I am getting a run time error .

Application is just starting & getting crashed.

In `iOS` → `Main.cs` → `UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");`

How can I resolve this ?

Crash logs attached.

> Foundation.MonoTouchException has been thrown
>
> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
>   Reason: Application windows are expected to have a root view
>   controller at the end of application launch Native stack trace:   0
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cf3c1bb
>   **exceptionPreprocess + 331   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010dec2735 objc_exception_throw + 48    2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010cf3bf42 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98    3
>
>   Foundation                          0x000000010c0f5877
>   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 194     4
>
>   UIKitCore                           0x00000001162c217a -[UIApplication
>   _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2978   5   UIKitCore                           0x0000000115ae04e9 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability
>   _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 866     6   UIKitCore                           0x0000000115ae929c +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000115ae0126
>   -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 233     8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000115ae0ae0
>   -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1085     9   UIKitCore
>
>   0x0000000115adecb5 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas
>   _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 795     10  UIKitCore                           0x0000000115ade95f -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 435     11  UIKitCore                           0x0000000115ae3a90
>   __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke
>   + 584     12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000115ae480e _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100   13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000115ae37ef -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction
>   performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]
>   + 221     14  UIKitCore                           0x0000000115ae893a -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392     15  UIKitCore                           0x00000001162c044e
>   -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 515     16 
>   UIKitCore                           0x0000000115e64d09
>   -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 357   17 
>   FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001119552da -[FBSSceneImpl
>   _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111960443
>   __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 271     19 
>   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011195fb3a
>   __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 53    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f3dc54b
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8  21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f3df60b _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 312  22 
>   FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111994ba8
>   __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 30     23  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111994860
>   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 457  24  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111994e40 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] +
>   45    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cea1721
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cea0f93
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243   27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ce9b63f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263    28  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010ce9ae11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625     29  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000111bb91dd GSEventRunModal + 62   30  UIKitCore
>   0x00000001162c381d UIApplicationMain + 140    31  ???
>   0x000000012cb7629e 0x0 + 5045183134   32  ???
>   0x000000012cb76033 0x0 + 5045182515

Comment: Are you assigning any Root view controller from your AppDelegate? Or If your Xamarin Forms App does initializing any MainPage?
Can you initialize the Empty view controller from your AppDelegate and later open the Xamarin Forms App? 
Can you open any other page than your current page you are opening from your AppDelegate/Xamarin Forms App?

These are all the possibilities you may want to test before.

Comment: @NirmalSubediI will try all these & will let you know

Comment: Try to link Use SDK assemblies Only from the option it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `Link all assemblies` instead of `Link SDK assemblies only` to reduce APK/IPA file size.

It reduces ~20MB for both iOS & Android.

For iOS I have to add `[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]` in all `dependency service` implementation. Now everything works fine.

Comment: hi chakkappaa, what is the use of   [Preserve(AllMembers = true)].